# How to check if a contact is google contact or not in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cncontactstore, ios-contacts

I am working on an app where I need to check if a contact is google contact or not for IOS.
After reading Contacts Framework what I understood was a contact can belong to multiple containers. Basically, containers are the server accounts where contacts are synced.
I tried to get the containers of contact but was not able to identify from the returned info that the contact is google contact or not.

Is there any way from which I can check for the same and get google id of the contact if it's a google contact?

Comment: I think you would need to use Google APIs directly

Comment: @Paulw11,  Not hitting a Google API is a constraint. The same thing is possible in Android. Android has the same thing as Containers called RawContacts from where we can get the info about where the contact is created/synced. I just want to know if a contact lies in  a google Container in ios. Is this even possible in ios?

Comment: I don’t believe so.

Comment: `CNInstantMessageServiceGoogleTalk` just to throw some word in here.